# Advanced filter function to get unique values only returns first record in column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some code to get a list of unique values from a column of data with the results copied into a different column using advanced filter. I initially got this code by using the "Record Macro" feature, and it worked fine at first when I did this, but after changing the sheet it initially selects the code now seems to only return the first record in the column. This is the code:

```
Sheets("4").Select
Columns("BA:BA").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Columns( _
    "BL:BL"), unique:=True
```

Eventually I'm going to need to run this code over a bunch of different sheets at once so it needs to select whole columns rather than more specific ranges as the length of the data in BA is going to change in each sheet. I have no idea why but it seems to work when it's run on one sheet and then not work when the sheet initially selected is manually changed in the code (and a sheet named "4" definitely does exist). After the change, only the very first record in BA is returned in BL rather than a list of all unique records.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Range, instead of Columns.  I tested it and where Columns was failing (a list with names and numbers), Range worked.  Also, you can skip the .Select, and just go straight to moving data.

In this sample, there's an input box that prompts for the Sheet Name.  If it happens to just be a number, that's fine.  It's going to be treated as a string in the sheetName.

```
Dim sheetName As String

sheetName = Application.InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")

Sheets(sheetName).Range("E:E").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets(sheetName).Range("O:O"), unique:=True
```